# Can't inject component into component via constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

I am trying to call private login: `LoginComponent`, however, my website wont load when I add private login: `LoginComponent`. My website load and runs fine before I add Login to the Constructor.  What am I doing wrong? Can I not call private login: `LoginComponent`? I have attached class `LoginComponent` below.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import * as Rx from "rxjs"
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment"
import {LoginComponent} from "app/components/login/login.component"
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth/auth.service"
import { LoginService } from "../../services/login/login.service"
import { SageApiService } from "../../services/sage-api/sage-api.service"
import { DataModel } from "../../model/data-model"
// wvj contract

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contract-form',
    templateUrl: './contract-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contract-form.component.css']
})
export class ContractFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('staticModal') staticModal;

    dataModel: DataModel = new DataModel()

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private sageApi: SageApiService,
        private login: LoginComponent
    ) { }
}
```

I am trying to call this class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { LoginService } from "../../services/login/login.service";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth/auth.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    error: string = "";
    username: string = "";
    password: string = "";
    isLoading: boolean = false;
    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: Define "blow up". Precisely. Post the code that "blows up". A class can't be called. Only functions/methods/constructors can be.

Comment: My website won't load. It loads perfectly fine before I add LoginComponent. I am trying to return a value on LoginComponent to ContractFormComponent

Comment: I am taking about when I add logincomponent to the  constructor() on ContractFormComponenet

Comment: Why are you trying to inject a component via the constructor?

Comment: There is a value on LoginComponent that I am trying to return to ContractFormComponent.

Comment: Stop describing your code in a vague way. Post it instead.

Comment: @CC41325 In that case, either do so via service, or do so using an EventEmitter

Comment: Also don't `import * as Rx from "rxjs"`, that imports the entire Reactive Extensions library, which is _huge:_ only import the operators you use (which seem to be...none)?

Comment: All I had to do was add LoginComponent to the provides in the app.moudles.ts main file. I got it work. I actually didnt even need to do that,  I just made a "localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(this.username));" then "this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username')); }"

Answer (score 5):

Any data passing between components can take place by 2 methods:

1. Create a service and inject that service in both components. The data to be shared between the components is done via the service.
2. Create a `Subject` in one component and `subscribe` to it in the other component.

**One component cannot be injected via constructor into another component.**

Comment: You can actually inject components which are in the same view hierarchy:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree

Answer (score 1):

You can call any function or variable of another component using dependency injection. Here is an example.

```
import { LoginComponent } from "app/components/login/login.component"

export class ContractFormComponent implements OnInit {

  loginComponent: LoginComponent

  constructor( private _login: LoginComponent ) {
    this.loginComponent = _login;
  }

  callAnythingFromLoginComponent() {
    this.loginComponent.anyFunctionFromLoginComponent();
  }
}
```